# What is the certification number for Microsoft VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I want to get certified in Microsoft VSTS. If exists, what's the exam code?

I've seen the TFS ALM: **[70-498](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/learning/exam-70-498.aspx) [Delivering Continuous Value with Visual Studio Application Lifecycle Management]**.

Does it serve the purpose? Please suggest

Comment: I know its not a very relevant question over here but i dint find a better place /people.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is No.

For VSTS, there doesn't exist certification exam.

For TFS, the related certification exam is [Exam 70-496](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-496.aspx). And it can accomplish technical tasks as below:

> - Installand configure Team Foundation Server (TFS) (25-30%)
> - Manage Team
>     Foundation Server (25-30%)
> - Customize Team Foundation Server for team
>     use (20-25%)
> - Administer version control (25-30%)

Comment: Thank you @Marina-MSFT. 
Can i know the exact difference between VSTS & ALM

Comment: VSTS is a kind of ALM, you can refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fda2bad5(v=vs.120).aspx to find the way TFS/VSTS with ALM. For more detail instructions about VSTS, you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/index#pivot=services.